# deserialization of an image from json using NSJSONSerialization

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsjsonserialization

I'm trying to deserialize JSON coming from the server using NSJsonSerialization. The server returns a png image converted to a string.
Here is my code:

```
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        NSError *deserializationError;
        id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers | NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&deserializationError];
        if (deserializationError) {
            NSLog(@"JSON deserialization error: %@", deserializationError.localizedDescription);
            return;
        }
} ];
```

Here is what I receive from the server:

```
{"photo":"�PNG\r\n\u001A\n\u0000\u0000\u0000\rIHDR\u0000\u0000\u0000:\u0000\u0000\u0000:\b\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000n��\u007F\u0000\u0000\u001FrIDATx�}z\u0005W[y��|��..."}
```

But i've got an error parsing JSON: "JSON deserialization error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)".
I think that the problem is with the format of JSON. But guys, that write server side say that they can successfully deserialize this object. Any suggestions how to deal with this JSON?

Comment: Are you getting the Base64 format of PNG ?

Comment: Do you have any control over this web service? Having a web service return an embedded image is bad form. If at all possible, have the web service return a link to the image. `{"photo": "http://<host>/<path>/<image>.png" }`. It will cut down on the size of each web service message and allow the client to cache the image.

Comment: I need to get information about users. Each user have an avatar. I need to download this information from the server to use it offline if needed. So the idea was to download all the information with one request instead of downloading every image apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know a JSON response must be string. The image you are getting looks like image data which is breaking the JSON parse with [`NSPropertyListErrorMinimum`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003793-CH3g-SW6) (*Cocoa error domain: 3840*). The server side JSON needs to send image encoded as a base64 string. This will keep the JSON valid at client side..

You can decode the base64 encoded image to get the image data at client side. Use [this `NSData` category](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64) which will help you decode the base64 string to `NSData`.

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:base64JSONString];
// Create image with data
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

`ImageData` can't directly transfer to `NSString`,
you can do this by `GMTBase64`:

Encode

```
NSString *imgStr = [GTMBase64 stringByEncodingData:imageData];
```

Decode

```
NSData *imageData = [GTMBase64 decodeString:imageStr];
```

Convert to Image

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:imageData];
```